# what is nt!PsActiveProcessHead?

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg, kernel-module

Background:
When using volatility, the variable `PsActiveProcessHead` can be found by `KDBG` scan (of a dead system), or it can be found on Windows Crash Dump (again, dead system) at `_DMP_HEADER`.

In a live system, the address of this symbol can be found by
(lkd>> x nt!PsActiveProcessHead)

Question:
To which windows kernel object/structure the `nt!PsActiveProcessHead` variable belongs to/refers to? (to which object/structure this symbol points to?)

For example, the `ActiveProcessLinks` which also is a `_LIST_ENTRY` structure (same as `ActiveProcessHead`) belongs to `_EPROCESS` object. Is there such an object for the `ActiveProcessHead` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it also points to a doubly linked list (`_LIST_ENTRY`), and more precisely to `_EPROCESS.ActiveProcessLinks`.

Checking the doubly linked list pointed to by `nt!PsActiveProcessHead`:

```
0: kd> dt nt!_list_entry poi(nt!PsActiveProcessHead)
 [ 0xffffc582`ca5c3328 - 0xfffff804`40c10680 ]
   +0x000 Flink            : 0xffffc582`ca5c3328 _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffc582`d11d1328 - 0xffffc582`ca4b15e8 ]
   +0x008 Blink            : 0xfffff804`40c10680 _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffc582`ca4b15e8 - 0xffffc582`edada368 ]
```

Next entry:

```
0: kd> dt nt!_list_entry poi(0xffffc582`ca5c3328)
 [ 0xffffc582`d0023428 - 0xffffc582`ca5c3328 ]
   +0x000 Flink            : 0xffffc582`d0023428 _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffc582`d54243a8 - 0xffffc582`d11d1328 ]
   +0x008 Blink            : 0xffffc582`ca5c3328 _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffc582`d11d1328 - 0xffffc582`ca4b15e8 ]
```

Getting the offset at which the `ActiveProcessLink`is in the `_EPROCESS` structure:

```
0: kd> ? @@c++(#FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_eprocess, ActiveProcessLinks))
Evaluate expression: 744 = 00000000`000002e8
```

Just confirming with the first two flinks I have in the above outputs (note: we remove the offset of `ActiveProcessLinks`from the address that we have, and then dump the `ImageFileName` from the EPROCESS structure). It just proves that it is really pointing to `ActiveProcessLinks` in `_EPROCESS`:

```
0: kd> dt nt!_eprocess 0xffffc582`ca5c3328-@@c++(#FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_eprocess , ActiveProcessLinks)) ImageFileName
   +0x450 ImageFileName : [15]  "Registry"

0: kd> dt nt!_eprocess 0xffffc582`d0023428-@@c++(#FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_eprocess , ActiveProcessLinks)) ImageFileName
   +0x450 ImageFileName : [15]  "csrss.exe"
```

Dumping the whole list:

```
0: kd> !list "-t nt!_eprocess.ActiveProcessLinks.Flink -e -x \"dt nt!_eprocess ImageFileName\"(poi(nt!PsActiveProcessHead) - @@c++(#FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_eprocess, ActiveProcessLinks)))"

dt nt!_EPROCESS ImageFileName 0xffffc582ca4b1300
   +0x450 ImageFileName : [15]  "System"

dt nt!_EPROCESS ImageFileName 0xffffc582ca5c3040
   +0x450 ImageFileName : [15]  "Registry"

dt nt!_EPROCESS ImageFileName 0xffffc582d11d1040
   +0x450 ImageFileName : [15]  "smss.exe"

dt nt!_EPROCESS ImageFileName 0xffffc582d0023140
   +0x450 ImageFileName : [15]  "csrss.exe"

 [...snip....]
```

So basically it is meant to be a list of the currently active process. It points to the doubly linked list in `_EPROCESS.ActiveProcessLinks`.